# How to make image 2D and RGB

Tags: python, gif, animated-gif

I'm using `iageio.imwrite()` when using this i keep getting a `ValueError` saying image must be 2D (grayscale, RGB, or RGBA). My input array has a size of 20,125,125. Is this the issue?

```
imageio.imwrite('patterns.gif',u_e, format = 'GIF-PIL', fps = 100)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is `u_e`? Is it a collection of 20 images? Is it  a single image with 20 color channels? I'm a bit confused

Comment: I'll link you the full code you will see what i mean better that way. https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20191212155033AAZMVui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to create a .gif with 20 frames (first dimension of `u_e`), each frame being a 125X125 grayscale image. If that's the case, I would use the `mimsave` function instead of `imwrite`:

```
imageio.mimsave('patterns.gif', u_e, format = 'GIF-PIL', fps = 100)
```

Here's the output:

[image]